# Axis guide line problem

Tags: interface, edit-mode, axis

When translating in edit mode, axis guidelines appear, blocking the view of thin objects and the 3d-cursor hides. Someway to hide the axis guidelines? I mean the blue line in the middle of the screen.[image]

Answer (score 1):

In user views, you can control the visibility of the axes and grid floor in the 'Display' panel of the properties region in the 3D View window.

[image]

I don't know why, but this doesn't work in the preset orthographic views (Top, Left, etc.). To hack out of that, convert the preset view to a user view from exactly the same angle, by tilting away and back again: <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>. It might be more convenient to align your view to a selected face, or an object's Z axis, using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>.